# Prevent 'new drive' popup for my USB 3G modem

Tags: windows-7, windows, usb-flash-drive, 3g

Whenever I insert my 3g modem, I get the 'install ____.exe' or 'View files' popup. I also get this periodically without re-inserting it, maybe because it restarts itself or something. Is there any way I can prevent this happening, preferable only for this device?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I request you to update the latest driver or bug fixes of your 3G modem by searching their hardware website ,Sure it will helps because preloaded driver are old and may have bugs.

If install.exe appears every time when you insert your modem ,try to disable the autorun of removable drives option in windows.

And this page will help you to disable specific drives ,by editing the registry.
http://support.microsoft.com/kb/967715

Comment: Thanks, but that page doesn't apply to Windows 7.